# HTML5 - Browse for html file, and add code into textarea

Tags: html, dom, import

I'm trying to avoid using PHP for this cause this app will be converted to an Android application. Been searching for a few hours and no luck. Again I want to avoid using PHP, and stick with HTML5.

Closest I can come across is this - http://www.script-tutorials.com/pure-html5-file-upload/

Just not sure how to utilize this with text from an .html document.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to place the entire contents of a file into a `textarea`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically just use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read the file from a file input and place the result in a text area.

```
<input type="file" onchange="loadfile(this)">
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

```
function loadfile(input){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
        document.getElementById('text').value = e.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8zVWk/